# Clearing all lists that are contained in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists
`sensors = [[] for i in range(8)]`

I want to empty all the sublists of the list.

I experimented with emptying one list only with:
`sensors[2].clear()` and i got:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

I am trying to make sense of this particular error, and what is the easiest way to clear all the sublists.

Comment: Can't you put a check `if isinstance(sensors[i], list)` before calling clear?

Comment: At some point you did `sensors[2] = an_int`, but since you didn't post an MCVE, it's impossible to tell why or how. Basic debugging is your responsibility.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'd appreciate if you used `[mcve]` instead of plain acronym, like this: [mcve].

Comment: @iBug. I didn't know that's an option. I assumed that if OP didn't know what it meant, they'd take the 3 seconds it takes to Google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some clearing of a list (of lists) and it worked fine, with `clear()`. The only time I received that error was when I tried to do this: `list[0][1].clear()` trying to clear a inner list's item. Instead to clear out that value (one of the values of the inner lists) I did `del list[0][1]` and it did it just fine.

So `clear()` should clear a list completely, or a list inside a list, BUT not a value in a inner list. Use `del` to get rid of a inner list value.